# Why doesn't my matrix store all my values? (C)

Tags: c, matrix, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on a problem in which i have to print out the reverse of the user-given words from the cmd. I also have to **increase** the allocated memory in case the number of inputs are greater than the originally given memory. *Memory allocation* and *reallocation* appear to be working fine. For some reason, my matrix only stores the **last given input** in all of its memory.

What is the problem? I even tried printing out the matrix cell values, but they are all filled with the last input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** create_matrix(int cap);
char** matrix_reallocation(char** matrix, int* cap);
void free_matrix(char** matrix, int cap);
void print_reverse_matrix(char** matrix, int words);

int main(){


    int cap = 8;
    char** matrix = create_matrix(cap);


    char tmp_word[1025];
    int words = 0;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%s",tmp_word) != EOF){
        matrix[words] = tmp_word;
        words++;
        printf("Words stored: %d, Capacity: %d\n", words, cap);
        if (words == cap){
            printf("Limit reached, reallocating....\n");
            matrix = matrix_reallocation(matrix, &cap);
        }
    }


    //printf("%s", matrix[0]);
    //printf("%s", matrix[1]);
    //printf("%s", matrix[2]);
    //printf("%s", matrix[3]);

    print_reverse_matrix(matrix,words);




    free_matrix(matrix,cap);
    return 0;
}


char** create_matrix(int cap){
    char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char*) * cap);
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1025);
        if (matrix[i] == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

char** matrix_reallocation(char** matrix, int *cap){
    char** new_matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(char*) * *cap * 2);
    printf("1D reallocated\n");
    *cap *= 2;
    printf("Capacity increased\n");
    for (int i = (*cap/2); i < *cap; ++i)
    {
        new_matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1025);
        if (new_matrix[i] == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Succesful reallocation, new capacity: %d\n", *cap);
    return new_matrix;
}

void print_reverse_matrix(char** matrix, int words){
    for (int i = (words - 1); i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", i+1);
        for (int j = (strlen(matrix[i]) - 1); j >= 0 ; j--)
        {
                printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void free_matrix(char** matrix, int cap){
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the loop you overwrite `tmp_word` and then assign a row in the matrix to it, making them all point to the same string. Instead, you should copy it to the matrix:

```
char tmp_word[1025];
int words = 0;
while (fscanf(stdin,"%s",tmp_word) != EOF){
    strcpy(matric[words], tmp_word); /* Here! */
    words++;
    printf("Words stored: %d, Capacity: %d\n", words, cap);
    if (words == cap){
        printf("Limit reached, reallocating....\n");
        matrix = matrix_reallocation(matrix, &cap);
    }
}
```